# Is there a way to 'slice' the results of a query into reportable chunks?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using the following VBA in Access 2010 to add a set of imported records to an existing linked table (tblPerson) from a temporary table (tblImport):

```
Dim dbs As Database        
Set dbs = CurrentDb
dim StrSQl as String
strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO tblPerson (GenID, Surname, GivenNames, OtherInfo, GroupID) " 
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT FHID, Surname, GivenNames, OtherInfo, Group FROM tblImport;"
dbs.Execute strSQL
```

For large data sets (definitely 750,000 records but probably smaller than that -- threshold to be determined) -- I'd like to provide a progress indicator for the import, so that the user doesn't lose hope and go into a terminal decline (or terminate the application because they can't see any progress.)  Importing such large files should be infrequent enough that the tradeoff between import time and progress reporting should be acceptable.

One option I'm considering is to split the dataset into (say) 10,000 record chunks and update progress after each one.

To achieve this I could use:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 FHID, Surname, GivenNames, OtherInfo, Group FROM tblImport ORDER BY FHID;
```

followed by

```
DELETE FROM tblImport 
WHERE FHID IN 
SELECT TOP 10000 FHID, Surname, GivenNames, OtherInfo, Group FROM tblImport ORDER BY FHID;
```

to determine the data to be imported each time and then delete it (at which point I'd report progress) and iterate until there aren't any records left in tblImport.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is `tblImport.FHID` a numeric primary key?

Comment: @HansUp No, it's a 50 character text field I have no control over.

Comment: Can you add an autonumber field to the `tblImport` temporary table?

Comment: @HansUp, yes if it;s useful and the performance impact isn't huge. I don't have to transfer to the ultimate destimation table (which has its own autonumber index)

Comment: With an autonumber primary key, you can open `tblImport` as a recordset and `rs.Move 10000` rows  at a time to get the pkey value at each chunk boundary.  Execute an `INSERT` for each chunk, using the boundary value in the `WHERE` clause.  Moving through an 11 million row table 10K rows at a time took less than 10 seconds, so for your 750K row table the performance load should not be a deal-breaker.

Comment: Do you have a requirement for `DELETE FROM tblImport` one chunk at a time?  Or was that an artifact of your initial strategy?

Comment: @HansUp It was an artefact of the original strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an autonumber field, *pkey*, as primary key to the `tblImport` temporary table.  Then you can open `tblImport` as a recordset and `rs.Move 10000` rows at a time to get the `pkey` value at each chunk boundary. Execute an `INSERT` for each chunk, using the boundary value in the `WHERE` clause.

Moving through an 11 million row table 10K rows at a time took me less than 10 seconds, so for your 750K row table, I'll guess the performance impact will be tolerable.